# Why isn't image size showing in admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added this code to my themes functions.php

```
// Image sizes
add_image_size( 'wide-thumb', 180,125);

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'dsbjj_my_custom_sizes' );

function dsbjj_my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'wide-thumb' => __( 'Wide Thumbnail' ),
    ) );
}
```

When I got to edit an image in the media library I cannot see "wide-thumb".  I have tried running regenerate thumbnails but no joy.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: u tried just uploading a new image, instead running regenerate thumbnails

Comment: Same thing.  I can call the image in my code but it doesn't appear under thumbnail settings in media library

Comment: is it possible, u have another plugin that is conflicting with  `image_size_names_choose`  filter.  try deactivating any plugins and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of time has passed, but I was having the same issue tonight and found a solution. Instead of

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'dsbjj_my_custom_sizes' );

function dsbjj_my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'wide-thumb' => __( 'Wide Thumbnail' ),
    ) );
}
```

I had to refactor my code to pass my function as the second parameter to `add_filter`, like so:

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', function ( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'wide-thumb' => __( 'Wide Thumbnail' ),
    ) );
} );
```

I came up with this solution after right-clicking the empty 'Size' dropdown on the Media select screen and choosing 'Inspect Element', which allowed me to see the error. I'm not sure if changes in WordPress or my host (Site5) caused the issue, but I hope this answer will help someone.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue. As shown [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109839/image-size-names-choose-filter-doesnt-show) you will need to **upload a new image before the size will be selectable**. Also you might need to **regenerate thumbnails**

Comment: I can't get the Size option to even show.  Not sure why but all I see is filter media by images, uploaded to this post, etc. select box and dates selectbox.  I've tried using this filter, and regenerated thumbnails, but still doesn't show a size dropdown anywhere in the backend.